# iTerm2: automatically remove $ sign in copied commands

Tags: command-line, shell, iterm

When we copy paste commands from articles on the web, there is often a `$` at the beginning.  Is there a way to automatically remove it when pasting it into iTerm?

Comment: It is very risky to copy paste commands from web into terminal.  Better to paste them into text editor first.  See : https://thejh.net/misc/website-terminal-copy-paste

Answer (score 3):

[@Ruslanic’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1419829/167207) is mostly there, but the regex is too broad and will remove:

- any single character followed by a space
- to a # that comments out the line
- a dot as a parameter.

For example, `ls . -l` turns into `l. -l`

Additionally, the use of a capture group is unnecessary, because the match will be removed if no substitution is provided.

A safer regex would be `^[\$]\h`

Explanation:

```
^[\$]\h
^          # Beginning of line only
 [\$]      # Match a single $ literally, could add more characters to remove if wanted
     \h    # Match a horizontal whitespace character (space or tab)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with RegEx.

Open iTerm and go to the menu:

iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Keys.

Under "Key Mappings" click on <kbd>+</kbd> and scroll down to "Paste..."

Check the entry:

✓ Replace `. (.+)` with `$1`

This will remove the first character and a whitespace after it from the text on paste.

Assign a shortcut to this action.

Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I find this tool very useful: [thefuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck).

Basically you copy and paste any $-prefixed command like `$ pip install tensorflow` and type `fuck`
it will give the right one: `pip install tensorflow`.

Answer (score 0):

To add on onto [@Dash's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1563594/698068), here's an updated regular expression that works with multi-line text such as:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
```

1. For the `Replace` field, use: `(^|\v)\h*[\$>]\h+`
2. For the `with` field, use: `$1`

Note that you *must* also set `$1` for the `with` field.

It also handles any whitespace before the `$` prompt character as well as allow `>` as a prompt character.

The `(^|\v)` matches the beginning of the line OR a [newline character](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html#regular-expression-metacharacters). Because the default replacement text is nothing, we need to capture the newline using `(...)` and then use the captured text, `$1` as the replacement, which puts the newline back. But it *only* puts the newline back. The leading prompt and any whitespace is removed.

The `\h*` matches zero or more horizontal whitespace, so even pasting this will work:

```
  $ mkdir foo
  $ cd foo
```

Here's a screen shot from iTerm2 version 3.4.19, where I've mapped `Control-Command-V` to this new `Paste` command:

[image: iTerm2 screen shot]